# Proving this using Cauchy criterion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence of non negative real numbers, show with the help of the Cauchy criterion for infinite series that $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ if $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges.

Now, I think I have proved this already by using the standard argument of if a series converges to L then the sequence of partial sums convergence to L,

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k=L$

it then follows that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$=$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} ( a_n+ \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k)$ = $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$ + $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k$

which leads to $L = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$ + L which implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n $= 0

But I don't understand how I'd do this using the Cauchy criterion and for the specific scenario specified in the question?

Comment: The you proof that you already have shouldn't be organized like that if it is not going to be explained further. The trivial way to obtain the last equation is by using directly that $\lim (x_n+y_n)=\lim x_n+\lim y_n$, but this requires that both $\lim x_n$ and $\lim y_n$ exist. You don't know at that point,yet, that $\lim a_n$ exists. You should organize it as $\lim \sum_{k=1}^n a_k - \lim \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k=\lim a_n$. Or better, explain how the last equation follows.

Comment: From the Cauchy condition you get, as a particular case that $|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k|\to 0$, by taking $m=n-1$ in $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta$ such that if $m,n>\delta$ then $|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k-\sum_{k=1}^ma_k|<\epsilon$.